# Excel - return value based on two inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two input values, that I want to use to return a third value.

`Input 1: Y (lets say "Y" is in cell B1) 
 Input 2: 15 (15 in cell B2)`

In another database sheet the input 1 values are sorted in the top row, the input 2 values are listed in a column in front of the wanted values.

`|  | X | Y | Z |
 |16| a | g | k |
 |15| b | h | l |
 |14| c | i | l |`

Fx. X,Y,Z are in row 3 and column 2,3,4.

I want a formula that returns "h" from the two inputs, Y & 15. How is this possible?

Comment: Are your inputs on the sheet (in cells) or somewhere else? How are the input values changed? Manually?

Comment: The input values are written in a input cell and can be found in a database in another sheet.  The input values will be changed manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above:

`=INDIRECT(B1&B2)` will return the value in `[Y15]` which is "h"

Comment: I see your point, and yes I have used this layout purely as an example to show how the `INDIRECT` function actually works, I don't follow the logic of the OP's matrix but if they care to elaborate I can update this answer to reflect.

Comment: Tried to simplify the matrix now.

Comment: Updated to reflect your example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `16` is in Row4, please try:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(CODE(B1)-22)&6-MOD(B$2,14))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula for you:

```
=INDEX(MatrixRange,MATCH(RowInput,MatrixStartColumn,0),MATCH(ColumnInput,MatrixStartRow,0))
```

MatrixRange = whatever the range of your data matrix is (in entirety) so if your data matrix starts in A3 and ends in D20 this would be replaced with A3:D20

RowInput = whatever cell you are getting search value for to find the row of appropriate data (This is Input 2 on your example)

MatrixStartColumn = Whatever column (or range) your Matrix data index starts in (these would be the numbers in your example). If the numbers on the left side of your data example are in Column A, this would be changed to A:A or A1:A50 (or wherever the last value is). The important thing for this is to use a range from the start of the column otherwise your row count will be off. If you must use a sub-range to avoid matches outside of the matrix, be sure to add the appropriate number to the end of the Match statement. For example if you are specifying MatrixStartColumn as "A3:A44", you will need to add +2 for the first 2 rows being skipped (A1 and A2). So the Index statement becomes (MatrixRange,MATCH(RowInput,MatrixStartColumn,0)+2,...

ColumnInput = whatever cell your column search value is in (your Input 1 data)

MatrixStartRow = Same as StartColumn above but for the header index of your matrix (the XYZ letters in your example). Just as above, if you must use only the range of the matrix, be sure to add your offset numbers so you get the right column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your inputs are at `B1` (row), and `B2` (Column) here is your formula:

`=INDEX(B4:D6,MATCH(B1,A4:A6,0),MATCH(B2,B3:D3,0))`

Here is how the formulas work:
 INDEX(area with values, row , column)  returns value based on row and column you provide.
 MATCH(value to find, range to search)  returns row/column where value was found.

Note that Match will accept only one row or column for 'range to search'.